# Faster way to restore MySQL innoDB dump

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-restore

I have a below MySQL configuration.

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
....
key_buffer = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 5M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
...
# enable GTID mode
gtid_mode = ON
enforce_gtid_consistency = 1


# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M

# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

Currently trying to restore a Mysql dump from below command on a different mysql host.

```
mysqldump -u <> -p <> --ssl-capath=<> -all-databases --triggers --routines --events --single-transaction --master-data >> /tmp/mysqldump
```

Restore the same dump using below command

```
cat /tmp/mysqldump | mysql -u <> -p <> --ssl-capath=<>
```

#### Current stats

mysql dump - 3 GB.
No network delays, on the same network

Dump generation time - 1 min
Restoration time - 9 min

Host RAM - 125 GB.
Swap - 8 GB

#### Methods tried to fasten up restoration

Updated mysql config to below

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M

# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
```

Disabling checks before dump and resetting them after dump.
Setting below before dump and resetting them after restoring dump

```
UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

**None of them fastened restoring database**

Any recommendations on ways to improve time to restore dump ?

Tried several possible ways to improve the time to restore dump. But none of them helped. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all the columns of each table indexes?  That would lead to a lot of time rebuilding indexes on the reload.  Is that `cat..|mysql..` running on the target machine?

Comment: yeah all tables have indexes on few columns. `cat ..| mysql..` is running from source machine to target machine. However, I tested running the same on target machine and doesn't have much difference in restoration times.

Comment: A slight improvement is to get rid of `cat`:  `mysql ... <file`

Comment: you mean get rid of `mysql < file` and use `mysqlimport` ?. Even though I guess it wouldn't be of big improvement I guess.

Comment: Original use case was to flip primary or RW host during failover, when flipping replication is broken with a below error. As a fallback step we are taking a dump and restoring which turns out to be a cumbersome process to restore replication across 20+ hosts.

to switch primary we run below command on slave
``` stop slave
change master to ...
start slave
```

Some times it works but it is broken at times. Not sure when would it break

Comment: `error 1236, Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'The slave is connecting using CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the slave requires. Replicate the missing transactions from elsewhere, or provision a new slave from backup. Consider increasing the master's binary log expiration period. The GTID sets and the missing purged transactions are too long to print in this message. For more information, please see the master's error log or the manual for GTID_SUBTRACT.'`

Comment: Recommend moving this "DBA" question to dba.stackexchange.com (stackoverflow attracts SQL experts).

Comment: thanks, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287493/faster-way-to-restore-mysql-innodb-dump